# Visual Studio 2013: Slow debugging performance

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 2.  I have an issue debugging a solution comprising around 100 C++ and Fortran projects.  Running the code through the debugger performs normally, but when I try to step over a breakpoint, even a simple assignment such as `int i = 0;` takes several seconds before advancing to the next line.

My debug exe is large but the machine has plenty of available RAM and should easily cope with this (c. 150Mb).  The exe itself is C++ and is built from statically linked libs.

I have tried deleting PDBs, cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: Are you caching debug symbols?

Comment: No, not caching symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the solution and deleting the SDF file has fixed the issue. I can now step over code as normal.

The new SDF file is 400 MB - half the size of the old file.  It seems to grow during debugging, so it may be necessary to repeat this housekeeping in future.